# How do i not skip a line if the return key is pressed

Tags: c#, keyboard

So I have code that separates input after each period. Then each sentence is put on separate lines. How do I make sure that in the input if you press return you don't skip a line? here is my code:

```
    string input = TextEditor.Text;
        string[] tokens = input.Split('.');
        Output.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tokens);
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Enter))  // for some reason words "Keyboard" and "Key" Don't work.
        {
            // I don't know what to do here
        }
```

So at the moment if I wrote:

```
Hello I am a human.
A good human
```

I would get an output of:

```
Hello I am a human

A good human
```

Comment: You could replace all "./n" by using `input.Replace(".\n", ".").Split...` or you do `tokens.Where(s =>! string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s))` when you join the strings

Comment: Should be \n @Timo :)

Comment: :) damn it. I updated the comment

Comment: @Timo When I do that I get an error at IsNullOrWhitespace. It says: "string does not contain a definition of IsNullOrWhitespace"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preprocess your input string by replacing all occurences of ".\n" with "." (this effectivly removes all line breaks when the line ends with a dot).

```
input.Replace(".\n", ".").Split('.')
```

Or you can postprocess the tokens by removing all strings form the array that are pure whitespace (new line, tab, whitespace).

```
Output.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tokens.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)));
```

**Update**

In case you are below .Net 4.0 you could do

```
Output.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tokens.Where(s => s != "\n" && s != "\r\n")));
```

Comment: When I do that I get an error at IsNullOrWhitespace. It says: "string does not contain a definition of IsNullOrWhitespace"

Comment: @DrummingAce which version of .Net do you use? string.IsNullOrWhitespace comes with .Net 4.0. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm not sure but I do use a version of .net 4.something. Which ever one comes with visual studios 2015 is the one I use

Comment: @DrummingAce Oh I have a typo there. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the line break. Try replacing **Environment.NewLine** with **String.Empty**

Comment: that doesn't really work because I still needed it as if when I put a period the rest of the string will be put a new line.